# ImageMagick command line usage

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have an application which exports scanned pdf-documents.

Now the scanned documents are not of the highest quality. That is why I'm enhancing them with ImageMagick.

Until last version, it worked like this:

```
    C:\Programme\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q8\convert.exe -enhance -colorspace gray -negate -lat 40x40+4% -contrast-stretch 0 -negate -density 300x300 "w.pdf" "x.pdf"
```

Now I changed to version 7.3.0-Q8, where the convert.exe is renamed to magick.exe

Same Command wont work anymore. Why?

Comment: I believe with V7 is more important to get the options etc. in the correct order. V6 was not as strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ImageMagick forums, it seems that you have to check some checkboxes when installing ImageMagick, to get the legacy executables :

> The IM 7 for Windows installation process has a series of windows,
>   including a load of checkboxes. About half way down one of these is
>   wording something like **"Install legacy components (convert.exe etc)"**.
>   Tick this box.

This is taken from the following topic : [convert.exe missing from 7.0.1-Q16?](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29582)

Answer (score 2):

Add up to answer by Berger, starting from IM7, the checkbox should shown during installation. It looks exactly the same as following screenshot:

Screenshot of setup executables :

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for the nice addition of the actual window :)

Answer (score 0):

convert.exe -enhance -colorspace gray -negate -lat 40x40+4% -contrast-stretch 0 -negate -density 300x300 "w.pdf" "x.pdf"

Try

```
magick.exe -density 300x300 "w.pdf" -enhance -colorspace gray -negate -lat 40x40+4% -contrast-stretch 0 -negate "x.pdf"
```